# Who are the people on the cover of James Joll's Europe since 1870?

Tags: europe

[image: front cover]

I see Hitler, Churchill, Marx, Queen Victoria, a well-known photograph of a newsboy after France, England, New Zealand and Australia declared war on Germany on 3 Sept. 1939.

That's as far as I get...

Comment: Well, Lenin and Stalin do not deserve?

Comment: Don't you have an image with better definition? Some of the smaller faces are difficult to match.

Comment: Doesn't the inside of the cover have a "key" somewhere? I've seen that in other history books with picture montages.

Comment: @T.E.D. No, unfortunately no key.

Answer (score 6):

While I think that this should be moved to History.SE, I will begin the answer.

1. Queen Victoria of the United Kingdom is the only woman.  Upper left with a crown.
2. The one who looks like Benito Mussolini is Benito Mussolini (in case you need more clues, he is under Queen Victoria, to the left).
3. [Karl Marx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karl_Marx) (German philosopher who wrote the Communist Manifesto) is in the center of the top row.
4. [Adolf Hitler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adolf_Hitler) (leader of Nazi Germany during World War II) is in the second row from the bottom, in the middle.  He has a Nazi swastika on his sleeve.
5. [Francisco Franco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francisco_Franco) (right of Adolf Hitler).
6. Philippe Pétain (left of Adolf Hitler).
7. Franz Joseph I of Austria (right of Karl Marx). Initally I thought him to be William I of Germany, but he seems a lot more like Franz Joseph.
8. Winston Churchill (Prime Minister of the UK during WWII) is the second from the bottom on the right side.
9. Charles De Gaulle right under Winston Churchill (maybe in the French edition they will switch their positions?)
10. The man right of Franz Joseph could be William II of Germany, in particular the moustache seems to be very telling but of course maybe that style was popular back in the day.
11. The man between Queen Victoria and Philippe Pétain is Edward VII of Gt Britain, son of Victoria and father of George V.
12. The one directly between Francisco Franco and Karl Marx seems to be [Léon Blum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9on_Blum), Prime Minister of France.
13. Harold Wilson, Prime Minister of the United Kingdom (1964-1970, 1974-1976) directly beneath under Hitler, smoking a pipe.
14. Neville Chamberlain, British Prime Minister who preceded Churchill is the small figure squeezed between Franco and Churchill.
15. The man who is seen in the center is Oswald Mosley (hats off to WS2 for this one). A google search for "Oswald Mosley shouting" returns that picture, including the gesture he is doing with his hand. Unfortunately, all of the versions of the image I found that clearly stablish the name are in sites that I do not want to link to.
16. Photograph of a British newsboy after France, England, New Zealand and Australia declared war on Germany on 3 Sept. 1939, carrying poster reading "News of the World: War Declared (Official)."

    17. And how could he have possibly remained unidentified - perhaps because it's not a good picture of him. But the imposing figure between Marx and Queen Victoria is none other than the Grand Old Man of Britain's late-Victorian liberalism - William Ewart Gladstone, Prime Minister four times 1868-74, 1880-85, a few months in 1886, and 1892-94. (The years in between were mostly filled by his Conservative nemesis the other Grand Old Man, Benjamin Disraeli).
    18. The standing figure beneath Gladstone and Marx is David Lloyd George (British Prime Minister 1916-1922).

---

### Images

1. Queen Victoria

[image: Queen Victoria by Basano, image from Wikipedia]

2. Benito Mussolini

[image: Benito Mussolini, image from Wikipedia]

3. Karl Marx

[image: Karl Marx, image from Wikipedia]

4. Adolf Hitler

[image: Adolf Hitler, image from Wikipedia]

5. Francisco Franco

[image: Francisco Franco, image from Spanish Wikipedia]

7. Franz Joseph I of Austria

[image: Franz Joseph I of Austria, image from Wikipedia]

12. Léon Blum

[image: Léon Blum, image from Wikipedia]

13. Harold Wilson

[image: Harold Wilson, image from the Daily Telegraph]

14. Neville Chamberlain

[image: Neville Chamberlain - "Peace in our time", image from Wikimedia]

15. Oswald Mosley

[image: Oswald Mosley, image from Wikimedia]

17. William Ewart Gladstone

[image: William Gladstone, from Wikimedia]

18. David Lloyd George

[image: David Lloyd George, from Wikimedia]

Comment: +1 The one directly beneath Hitler, smoking a pipe is Harold Wilson, British Prime Minister from 1964 - 1970, and 1974-76. And yes, de Gaulle is beneath Churchill.

Comment: @WS2 (and everybody else), this is a community wiki, which means that everyone is invited to edit and add new content directly.

Comment: Isn't the one to the right of Marx, wearing a red tunic Chiang Kai-Shek? And the one under Marx, standing up is Albert Einstein.

Comment: And the small figure squeezed between Franco and Churchill is Neville Chamberlain, British Prime Minister who preceded Churchill.

Comment: I don't think Benito Mussolini is there.

Comment: @WS2 the eagle adorned beret is unmistakable: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benito_Mussolini#/media/File:Benito_Mussolini_Duce.jpg

Comment: You are probably right, but his face doesn't look fat enough for Musso. I think the one to the right of him and up a bit, beneath Victoria to the right is probably Tsar Nicholas II. I think the one to the right of Einstein could be Leon Blum, but the figure beneath them both - shouting - is so familiar, it is driving me mad thinking who it is.

Comment: I think it is Oswald Mosley - British fascist leader.

Comment: I think you are probably right about Franz Joseph and William II. You are right it would be ridiculous to have Chiang Kai Shek on the cover.

Comment: Quite surprising that Lenin, Stalin etc would have been excluded. I still can't decide who it is between Victoria and Marx.

Comment: Bottom right totally looks like [Charles De Gaulle](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/27/De_Gaulle-OWI.jpg).

Comment: For 11 my first guess was Sigmund Freud. Probably just the beard though. If the rest were politicians,@WS2 is probably right about it being Tsar Nicholas.

Comment: The standing man under Marx is definitely not Albert Einstein.

Comment: Re 12, what is meant by "between Franco and Queen Victoria"? There are a whole host of people there. Does it mean, the one above Franco? As yet no one has said who it is between Marx and Victoria - that one has me puzzled. And who is the diminished figure who has is arm around a tin-hatted soldier?

Comment: @T.E.D. Interesting that 11. I'm having doubts about Tsar Nick. He has a rather semitic look about him. But I don't think it's Freud.

Comment: @WS2 - Don't know what precisely you mean by that, but I'd suggest comparing it to actual [photos of the guy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicholas_II_of_Russia#/media/File:Nicholas_II_by_Boissonnas_%26_Eggler_c1909.jpg). To me at least it does look rather a lot like him. Notice the lighter spots in his beard to the sides of the gotee area near the lower lip. Do remember that the royal families of Russia, Germany, England, and some other states were really all the same family. Point being, looking for any visible ethnic affinity to their subjects amongst European royalty is a waste of time.

Comment: @T.E.D. What you say is right. I did for a moment wonder if it cold be George V. But it's probably Nicholas. Could the one between Victoria and Marx be Kruger, the Boer leader? Not strictly a European of course.

Comment: @WS2 another orienttion error about Léon Blum, I meant between Francisco Franco and Karl Marx (my screen is not big enough to look at the picture and write at the same time).

Comment: I believe it is Edward VII between Victoria and Petain, rather than Cecil or Nicholas II. The figure bears no resemblance to George V, who was a virtual twin of Nicholas in appearance. I concur with the Franz Joseph deduction.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens  Well done! I've been sitting here for two evenings, knowing the face but just not being able to put the right  name to it. Edward VII - of course. He was the father of George V.

Comment: But I'm still puzzled about the huge character to the left of Marx. Could it be Paul Von Hindenburg, German military commander in WW1, and later statesman? I don't really see how it could be because Hindenburg always sported a splendid moustache. Indeed it would have been unusual for a man of dignity to have been clean-shaven in that period. This figure seems to belong to a later decade, and he must have been important to have been given such prominence in the picture.

Comment: How could I possibly not have realised, it is the great father of British Liberalism - William Gladstone, Prime Minister four times 1868-74; 1880-85, a few months in 1886, and 1892-94.

Comment: It seems we are almost done, except for that we are not sure about Blum and Wilhelm II, though both look very plausible, and no one has yet identified the small figure under Marx that was earlier said to be Einstein (it looks nothing like Einstein on the physical cover -- if it is then the artist did a very poor job, and all the others are state figures, so it would be a bit weird anyway.) Also, no one has identified what are probably press photographs: the man in the bottom left corner and the men arm in arm next to Blum.

Comment: @Kappie001 If it's not Einstein it certainly looks like him, though I haven't seen the original cover. But who else could it possibly be? I am astonished that neither Lenin nor Stalin would be included - unless Russia doesn't count as Europe for Joll's purposes. We still haven't identified the small figure under Franz Josef, with his arm around a soldier.

Comment: @WS2 the cover seems to be rather biased towards British figures (both the number and the presence of such a minor character like Mosley would support that), and I guess that for some people the presence of Karl Marx represents all the Communist movement.

Comment: @SJuan76 Well Joll is a British writer, writing in English, essentially to a British reader. I suppose that's the point. In France this summer I noticed in almost all service stations these potted accounts of all kinds of things from the rudiments of computing, to homeopathy to the history of the French Revolution - to be read to the kids on car journeys, I suppose. I picked up the one entitled "Important figures of WW2". There was Hitler, Stalin, Petain, de Gaulle, Leclerc etc - but rather astonishingly not a single picture of Roosevelt or Churchill!

Comment: @WS2 I was just commenting about the absence of Lenin and Stalin, not trying to disqualify neither the book (which I have not read) nor the cover (which is not that important). As I hinted above somewhere, it is not so unusual for the cover (which is the main marketing material) to cater to the expected audience.

Comment: @Kappie001 The figure, postulated as possibly Einstein, appears to be wearing an academic gown. Would that be significant?

Comment: @Kappie001 Ah! I think it's David Lloyd George (British Prime Minister 1916 - 1922). I've seen [a picture of him](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=david+lloyd+george,+standing+up&num=50&tbm=isch&source=iu&pf=m&ictx=1&fir=6fbamqMhgwcSSM%253A%252CpDv29IdPBH_Q_M%252C_&usg=__DqpGqSXzfII13XyIIoZPbHnZQqc%3D&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi17Zu-ttzWAhUlIcAKHcw0Dr4Q9QEILDAB#imgrc=6fbamqMhgwcSSM:) wearing a cloak like that.

Comment: @Kappie001 The one postulated as Leon Blum might equally be Georges Clémenceau. But both he and Blum had droopy moustaches. This one's is quite different.

Comment: @WS2 David Lloyd George seems very plausible, from the likeness to the picture and his prominent role in the book. Georges Clémenceau seems more likely than Blum, since the figure has no glasses, and Clémenceau features prominently in the book. You're on a roll!